# tuple dict returning a list error?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a problem in my main program:

```
E, back = dict(), dict()

for C in range(cols+1): 
    E[0,C], back[0,C] = m[0,C], None
```

Which is returning me this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

I am so confused, because I have clearly initialized a dictionary not a list.

What's this error about, bot E and back are a dictionary as stated in the first line. But when I try adding elements it gives me a LIST error?

EDIT --- 
"m" is an array of pixels
"cols" is len(m[0])
The purpose of my code is to perform a vertical Seam Carving of an image stored in m, where m[x][y] is the greyscale of the pixel in the position x,y.
I don't want/need help with the seamcarving algorithm, but this error message is driving me nuts right now, doens't have any sense.

Okay, I corrected myself in the edit... I was trying to acces m as a dictionary, and it's indeed an array. Shame on me.

Comment: What is the type of `m`?

Comment: You say that it doesn't make sense, but you have a list of pixels, what is `m[0,C]` meant to get from the list? That is telling it to get the index `(0, C)` from the list, which makes no sense. You probably wanted `m[0][C]`.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shown all your code, but I'm guessing that `m` is a list.

Answer (score 3):

You've stated `m` is a list of lists. The syntax in Python for accessing an element of a sublist is not `[a, b]` it's `[a][b]`.

`m[0,C]` means access the element of `m` indexed by the tuple `(0, C)`.

What you want is to get element `0` of `m`, then element `C` of that element, so `m[0][C]`.

To show this clearly:

```
>>> a = [list(range(5)) for _ in range(5)]
>>> a
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> a[0, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
>>> a[0][2]
2
```

You can see the error makes complete sense.